# Slick & Derby problems with VARCHAR fields

Tags: derby, slick-3.0

I am trying to use Slick 3.1.1 together with Apache Derby, however at the generation of the table the code breaks.

Stepping through the code I found the problem to lie with the `VARCHAR` definition. Slick translates Strings to `VARCHAR`, but without putting a length:

```
def myfield = column[String]("myfield", O.PrimaryKey)
```

is translated to SQL as

```
"entity" VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

I could temporarily solve the problem by adjusting the definition to

```
column[String]("myfield", O.PrimaryKey, O.SqlType("VARCHAR(200)")
```

Is this really the way to use Slick and Derby together? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure about this, but have you tried adding `O.Length(200)` as option? Also if you need columns of undefined length, you should probably use "CLOB" instead. E.g. `column[String]("myfield", O.SqlType("CLOB")`.